# Ms Project: How to make Gantt chart focus on entire project using C#?

Tags: c#, office-interop, ms-project

- I'm trying to create an MPP file using C#.
- I succeeded but I had a small problem with the Gantt chart after finishing create MPP file I found the time scale of the Gantt chart in the present date so I make scroll to the first date time's task to find resources and predecessors of tasks
- I want to make the file open and focus automatically on the entire project of the Gantt chart.

namespace of ms- project is:

> using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //connect to API 
        var srv = new PMSgatewayClient();

        var projectuid = Guid.Parse("54d5bc97-19dd-e911-8102-00155d6b1204");

        //Get project from database
        var ProjectData = srv.Project_Get_Details(projectuid, Guid.Empty, false, false, Guid.Empty, App_Code.BasicClasses.BasicData.CurrentUser.Id, null, out ErrorCode, out ErorMessage);

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //Create the Application object to interact with MS project
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application appclass = new Application();
        appclass.Projects.Add(false, missing, missing);

        //Get the name of project from database
        string fileName = ProjectData.BasicInfo.DisplayName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MM mm ss ").Trim();

        //Create file in folder call temp with the name of project 
        appclass.ActiveProject.SaveAs($"{Server.MapPath("~/Temp")}/{fileName}.mpp", PjFileFormat.pjMPP, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

        //Get the active project in the file
        Project project = appclass.ActiveProject;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Resources resources = project.Resources;

        //We want to go through all the elements in the list
        Tasks tasks = project.Tasks; 

        // here i'm trying to make the Gantt chart focus on time scale of the project or focus on entire project
        project.LevelEntireProject = true;
        tasks.Application.ZoomTimescale("Days", true, false, false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire project to be visible in the Gantt chart, you can use this:

```
appclass.ZoomTimescale(Entire: true);
```

Comment: thank you, I added it into the code and I found resources and relations between tasks displayed but the Gantt chart doesn't focus on it. 
Gantt chart focus on the present date.
can you help me with this?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AhmedKhaled that code will show the entire project in the Gantt Chart, is that not what you wanted? If you want to the gantt chart to focus on today's date, use this: `appclass.EditGoTo(Date: DateTime.Today)`